# How to get value from a simple google maps address search with autocomplete in flutter and display the prediction it in TextFormField

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter, dart, google-places

In my code, I am searching for places with flutter_google_places from TextFormField like this:

```
TextFormField(
 decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'From')
 onTap: () async {
  Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show( context: context, apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);
  displayPrediction(p);
 },
)
```

And I want to display the result in the same TextFormField.
Here is my `displayPrediction()`:

```
Future<Null> displayPrediction(Prediction p) async {
if (p != null) {
  PlacesDetailsResponse detail =
  await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId);

  var placeId = p.placeId;
  double lat = detail.result.geometry.location.lat;
  double lng = detail.result.geometry.location.lng;

  var address = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(p.description);

  print(lat);
  print(lng);
}}
```

Here is the ScreenShot: [image]

Answer (score 0):

give a controller to your textfieldInput eg toController
ie: controller: toController,

then in your displayPrediction method, add
...

toController.text = address;